# Traverse XML using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this following XML:

```
<Item type="Workflow Process">
    <id>72F2AEEE86644D16ADE4B8FCEF68638A</id>
    <keyed_name>PR-100001</keyed_name>
    <Relationships>
        <Item type="Workflow Process Activity">
            <id>818175D7A6204275B9EAC45517FFC0DE</id>
            <related_id>
                <Item type="Activity">
                    <id>E0B712EB12914FBD8B5AEDCBDB3F313F</id>
                    <keyed_name>Start</keyed_name>
                </Item>
            </related_id>
        </Item>
    </Relationships>
</Item>
```

**Note:** The above XML structure is repeated in my XML file with different values of `<id>` and `<keyed_name>`

I have `<id>` of `<Item type="Activity">`, I want to know the `<id>` of parent node `<Item type="Workflow Process">` to which that `Activity`belongs.

What will be the XPath to achieve it?

Comment: Can we see what you have tried so far ? A little bit of search on Google /StackOverflow will give this details or have a look at www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a reference to the inner `Activity` and can evaluate an XPath with that as the context node then

```
ancestor::Item[@type = 'Workflow Process']/id
```

If you just have the id and you're starting from the top of the tree then as long as all the ids are globally unique within the document the simplest I can think of is

```
//Item[@type = 'Workflow Process'][.//id = 'id you want']/id
```

I can't be more specific without knowing the context - is this in XSLT or are you using a DOM library of some sort (which one?).

Comment: Glad it helped, and welcome to SO.  If the answer worked for you, please consider _accepting_ it by clicking on the green tick mark to the left.  Building a track record of accepting good answers will mean people are more willing to answer your future questions.